# Cleaning html string for preventing XSS using HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that HtmlUnit can be used to filter html strings for preventing XSS, but am unable to find any clue how to. Does HtmlUnit provide this function, or  I need to use JSoup or something else for it?

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: Which language are you working on... java ?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to strip dirty html before saving to database.